# Newrelic plugin nginx-nr-agent not working

Tags: nginx, newrelic

I am using Newrelic's `nginx-nr-agent` but suddenly it crashed giving out the following error and not starting back.

```
2016-04-12 07:51:07,021 nginx-nr-agent [ERROR]: EXCEPTION: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/nginx-nr-agent.py", line 431, in newrelic_push
u = urlopen(r, data=json.dumps(payload))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 401, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 419, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1219, in https_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1034, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
line = self.fp.readline()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/daemon/daemon.py", line 399, in terminate
raise exception
SystemExit: Terminating on signal 15
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got two solution for this from [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/06/newrelic-nginx-nr-agent-not-running.html), one is to remove the pid file `/var/run/nginx-nr-agent/nginx-nr-agent.pid` and than `start/restart` it. And second solution is to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is published and supported by Nginx, Inc. If the previous suggestions did not help, contact
newrelic-support@nginx.com.